# PreferenceCompatFragment null pointer when setting OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, settings, support-preference

I'm using mentioned `PreferenceCompatFragment` in my code but I have a problem with setting listener on changing settings.

I have made an implementation of `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in my `Activity` so I have tried to set mentioned listener in a moment when Fragment will be attached to view/container but all time I'm getting null pointer on `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());`

Most examples are construct with such way that Fragment is implementing also listener - in my case i want to do it separately.

Answer (score 0):

I just found quite simple solution,

- `onCreatePreferences` - add preferences from resource
- `onAttach` - assign listener (global variable) from MainActivity
- `onCreate` - getPreferencesManager and register listener